# React update parent when children component updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, parent

Why parent component always show 1 less than child?
It's not re-rendered after first update.

```
export const Parent = (props) => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Parent: {count}</Text>
      <Child updateCount={setCount} />
    </View>
  );
};

const Child = (props) => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  const updateCount = () => {
    setCount((count) => count + 1);
    return props.updateCount(count);
  };
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Child: {count}</Text>
      <Button title="add" onPress={updateCount} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Do you want to make a carousel?

Comment: No, it's not a carousel. I make it simple counter and update a code.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is you are expecting `setCount` to be happening **immediately** although it is an **asynchronous** action. The problem is in your `<Child />` component in the below code:

```
const updateCount = () => {
    setCount((count) => count + 1)
    return props.updateCount(count)
}
```

Technically you are expecting `count` to be updated and passed to `props.updatedCount` meanwhile it's still has the previous value.

Also which is not related to the issue but you don't really need to return from the function where you update the state, so just removed `return` keyword.

---

There are different options to solve this issue.

1. ***Using still the separated states as in your code:***

Simply calling exactly the same way the `props.updateCount` as the other `setState` as:

```
const updateCount = () => {
  setCount((count) => count + 1)
  props.updateCount((count) => count + 1)
}
```

2. ***Keeping one state in `<Parent />` and passing down through props:***

So mainly the solution would be:

```
export const Parent = (props) => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Parent: {count}</Text>
      {/* passed here count as well: */}
      <Child updateCount={setCount} count={count} />
    </View>
  );
};

// destructure here updateCount and count
const Child = ({ updateCount, count }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      {/* using here count from parent */}
      <Text>Child: {count}</Text>
      {/* calling here updateCount from the props as: */}
      <Button title="add" onPress={() => updateCount((count) => count + 1} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

3. ***The third option would be to use [`Context` API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html):***

By using `Context` you can do the following, see from the documentation as:

> Context provides a way to pass data through the component tree without having to pass props down manually at every level.

Usually I like to use `Context` once we have more complex component tree than the current one. So I suggest to go with keeping one state option.

Comment: I answered 12 seconds before you haha

Comment: I always wondered if it was a good idea, or a good practice to pass the `setState` down to the child

Comment: @programmer I would stay it's not ideal to pass down through props the state updater function in a **complex component tree** but for the current scenario it is _totally fine_. Ideally once having a complex tree `Context` API can be used as I suggest in my solution.

Answer (score 1):

The solution N°2 of @norbitrial worked as a charm, in my case it is class components not functional components. here only to post an answer adapted to class components
So the idea is keeping on state in parent component and share it with the child as props. then make any operation we want on it in child component.

#### Parent.js

```js
export default class CraGenerator extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            number: 0
        }

    getNumberFromChild(data) {
            this.setState({ number: data });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.increment.bind(this)}>
                <Child getNumberFromChild={this.getNumberFromChild.bind(this)} number={this.state.number}/>
            </div>
            
        )
}
```

#### Child.js

```js
export default class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            number: this.props.number
        }
    }

    increment() {
        this.setState({ number: this.state.number + 1 });
        this.props.getNumberFromChild(this.state.number + 1);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.increment.bind(this)}>
                Click me...increment me ::: {this.state.number}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Move the logic part of your code to the parent** and leave the child as a button and text only instead. Do it like this:

```
 export const Parent = (props) => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  const handleCount = () => {
    setCount = count + 1
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Parent: {count}</Text>
      <Child updateCount={setCount} count={count}/>
    </View>
  );
};

const Child = (props) => {

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Child: {props.count}</Text>
      <Button title="add" onPress={()=>props.updateCount()} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I made an example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-sunset-ggfw1?file=/src/App.js):

```js
const updateCount = () => {
  setCount((count) => count + 1); // <=== you did it here correctly
  return props.updateCount(count); // the problem is here
};
```

This is happening because it's not receiving the latest value of count, which that happens on the next re-render, so it will always be one step behind. To fix this just do the same, `return` here is redundant.

```js
const updateCount = () => {
  setCount((count) => count + 1);
  props.updateCount((count) => count + 1); // problem fixed
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use state hoisting pattern to solve this issue as described in the other answers without naming it, i will reference a website as a good read about it you can use this pattern to solve many of those related issues, the other options are to start using redux or a  simpler state store in your application. redux is the biggest time investment and it has more boilerplate code to add.

[State hoisting react patterns](https://reactpatterns.js.org/docs/state-hoisting/)